# converting non-numeric to numeric value using Panda libraries

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning Pandas and I came to an interesting question. So I have a Dataframe like this:

```
COL1    COL2      COL3
a     9/8/2016     2
b     12/4/2016    23
         ...
n     1/1/2015     21
```

COL1 is a String, Col2 is a timestamp and Col3 is a number. Now I need to do some analysis on this Dataframe and I want to convert all the non-numeric data to numeric. I tried using [DictVectorizer()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#dict-feature-extraction) to convert COL1 and 2 to numeric but first of all I am not sure if this is the best way doing such a thing and second I don't know what to do with the timestamp.
When I use DictVectorizer the output would be like:

```
{u'COL3: {0:2, 1:23 , ...,n:21}, 'COL1': {0: u'a', 1:'b', ... , n:'n'}, 'COL2': {0: u'9/8/2016' , 1: u'12/4/2016' , ... , n:u'1/1/2016'}}
```

but from what I learned it should be like this or at least I know I need something like this:

```
 {COL1:'a', COL2: '9/8/2016' , COL3: 2  and so on}
```

so, questions:
1-what is the best way of converting non- numeric (including date) to numeric values to use in sklearn libraries
2- what is the right way of using DictVectorize()

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To encode non-numeric data to numeric you can use scikit-learn's [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder). It will encode each category such as COL1's `a`, `b`, `c` to integers.

Assuming df is your dataframe, try:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
enc = LabelEncoder()
enc.fit(df['COL1'])
df['COL1'] = enc.transform(df['col1'])
```

- `enc.fit()` creates the corresponding integer values.
- `enc.transform()` applies the encoding to the df values.

For the second column, using Pandas [to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function should do the trick, like @quinn-weber mentioned, try:

```
df['COL2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['COL2'])
```

Comment: @Faranak For `COL2` you can use Pandas [pd.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function:

    `df['COL2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['COL2'])`

Answer (score 1):

You could convert COL1 with something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
table = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a','9/8/2016',2],
    ['b','12/4/2016',23],
    ['n','1/1/2015',21],
], columns=['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'])
table['COL1'] = table['COL1'].map(dict(zip(list(string.lowercase), xrange(0,25))))
```

As for the timestamp, you could do:

```
table['COL2'] = pd.to_datetime(
    table['COL2'], format='%m/%d/%Y'
).dt.strftime(date_format='%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: mapping is manual? {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'n': 14}...my data is like 68k

Comment: 68k rows i mean

Answer (score 0):

for strings
consider

```
s = pd.Series(list('abcdefagbfhickjjmshh'))
# get unique values
u = s.unique()
# gen a mapping series
m = pd.Series(range(len(u)), u)
# encode
s.map(m)

0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
6      0
7      6
8      1
9      5
10     7
11     8
12     2
13     9
14    10
15    10
16    11
17    12
18     7
19     7
dtype: int64
```

for dates
there are two ways to do it.  If you don't care about the relative position of the dates, use the same exact method as for strings.  Otherwise
consider

```
d = pd.date_range('2015-03-31', periods=20).to_series().reset_index(drop=True)

pd.Series(d.values.astype(np.timedelta64), d.index, np.int64)

0     1427760000000000000
1     1427846400000000000
2     1427932800000000000
3     1428019200000000000
4     1428105600000000000
5     1428192000000000000
6     1428278400000000000
7     1428364800000000000
8     1428451200000000000
9     1428537600000000000
10    1428624000000000000
11    1428710400000000000
12    1428796800000000000
13    1428883200000000000
14    1428969600000000000
15    1429056000000000000
16    1429142400000000000
17    1429228800000000000
18    1429315200000000000
19    1429401600000000000
dtype: int64
```