# How to convert pandas data frame string values to numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data set. It has some string columns. I want to convert these string columns. I'm developing a Neural network using this data set. But since the dataset has some string values I can't train my Neural network. What is the best way to convert these string values to Neural Network readable format?

**This is the data set that I have**

```
type,amount,nameOrig,oldbalanceOrg,newbalanceOrig,nameDest,oldbalanceDest,newbalanceDest,isFraud,isFlaggedFraud
PAYMENT,9839.64,C1231006815,170136.0,160296.36,M1979787155,0.0,0.0,1,0
PAYMENT,1864.28,C1666544295,21249.0,19384.72,M2044282225,0.0,0.0,0,0
TRANSFER,181.0,C1305486145,181.0,0.0,C553264065,0.0,0.0,0,1
```

I want to convert those **type,nameOrig,nameDest** fields to neural network readable format.

I have used below method. But I don't know wheater it's right or wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

enc = LabelEncoder()

test_set = pd.read_csv('cs.csv')
new_test_set['type'] = enc.fit(new_test_set['type'])
```

I have gone through below questions. But most of them are not worked for me

[How to convert string based data frame to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933031/how-to-convert-string-based-data-frame-to-numeric)

[converting non-numeric to numeric value using Panda libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142686/converting-non-numeric-to-numeric-value-using-panda-libraries)

[converting non-numeric to numeric value using Panda libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142686/converting-non-numeric-to-numeric-value-using-panda-libraries][3])

Comment: "_Most of them are not worked_" - why not? What happened? What did you expect?

Comment: According to the third link question that I have added in links, I'm using the LabelEncoder.  But others are gave me some errors

Comment: You _should_ use the LabelEncoder. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use the datatype `category` of pandas to map strings to indices (see [categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)). So it's not necessary to use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) or [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) of [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('54055554.csv', header=0, dtype={
    'type': 'category',  # <--
    'amount': float,
    'nameOrig': str,
    'oldbalanceOrg': float,
    'newbalanceOrig': float,
    'nameDest': str,
    'oldbalanceDest': float,
    'newbalanceDest': float,
    'isFraud': bool,
    'isFlaggedFraud': bool
})

print(dict(enumerate(df['type'].cat.categories)))
# {0: 'PAYMENT', 1: 'TRANSFER'}

print(list(df['type'].cat.codes))
# [0, 0, 1]
```

The data from the CSV:

```
type, ...
PAYMENT, ...
PAYMENT, ...
TRANSFER, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the string values into numeric ones. What I usually do in this case is creating a table by a non numeric feature, the created table contains all the possible value of that feature. And then, the index of the value in the corresponding features table is used when training a model.

Example:

```
type_values = ['PAYMENT', 'TRANSFER']
```

Comment: Surely using the standard `LabelEncoder` is preferred to any _ad hoc_ solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Transformation

First you need to transform the three columns using `LableEncoder` class.

### Encoding Categorical Data

Well here you have the type as categorical value. For this you can use the class `OneHotEncoder` available in `sklearn.preprocessing`.

### Avoiding Dummy Variable Trap

Then you need to avoid the Dummy Variable Trap by removing any one of the column that are being used to represent type.

### Code

Here I have put the sample code for your reference.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

dataset = pd.read_csv('cs.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:].values

labelencoder = LabelEncoder()

X[:, 0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
X[:, 2] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
X[:, 5] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 5])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

# Avoiding the Dummy Variable Trap
X = X[:, 1:]
```